How to host/install vscode extension from private repository
I have built a vs code extension for internal purpose with in the organization and would like to distribute to the team members with in our organization. Is it possible to set a repo and configure vs code to look into that repo while someone searching for extension.
I know we can set up a custom npm repository using .npmrc configuration file. I was wondering whether the same is possible for vs code extensions.

You literally ask for recommendation on a private VS Code extension marketplace. Please use search engines for such, as they are off topic here.

Found below links.
VSCode Private Extension Repository for teams
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21839
The request to support external host for vs code extension is still open.
